# How to get the coordinates clicked on an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I need to get the x and y coordinates of where I clicked on an HTML5 canvas element.  I did the following for the y coordinate:

```
 $("#my_canvas").click(function(event) {
        alert(Math.floor(event.clientY-$(this).offset().top));
 });
```

This gives me what appears to be the correct y coordinate.  The problem is if you scroll down, `clientY` gets smaller because it seems to be measuring the y coordinate on the screen, disregarding the scrolling.  So the above gives a negative number.

What is the proper way to get the x and y coordinate?

Comment: You can also factor in `$(document).scrollTop()` to the top offset.

Comment: I think this is neither related to html5 nor to canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pageY](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/) instead of `clientY`, so that both the coordinates you compare are relative to the document :

```
event.pageY-$(this).offset().top
```