# How to get the coordinates of click/tap on canvas in Polymer/WebComponent (when inside scrolled container)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, polymer, web-component

I was aware of the usual method for finding the click position relative to the canvas, as has been [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416930/how-to-get-the-coordinates-clicked-on-an-html5-canvas) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element), which in brief is:

1. Grab `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` values to get the position of the click relative to the document
2. subtract the x and y coords of the canvas on the page, either with `canvasEl.offsetLeft`/`canvas.El.offsetTop` or using jQuery's `$(canvasEl).offset()`, recursing up through parents if necessary
3. Subtract the scroll position of the page and any parent elements, if any.

Sadly, this doesn't work when both the following are true:

1. The canvas is part of a Polymer (and I assume any other WebComponent solution that polyfills Shadow DOM) element
2. The canvas is positioned within a scrolling parent. I did some investigating into this and it looked like Polymer was skipping an ancestor when crossing the shadow boundary, meaning the scroll offset isn't calculated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I've come across this problem, even outside of WebComponents, my initial reaction has always been *why is it so hard to get the coordinates of a click on a canvas? Surely that's pretty crucial? Shouldn't the coordinates be calculated for you already?*

It turns out that they have, almost. As described [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23757599/4887407), The canvas API has a method `getBoundingClientRect()` which returns a `DOMRect` (`ClientRect` in Chrome):

```
{
    x: 348,
    y: 180.35000610351562,
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    top: 180.35000610351562,
    right: 476,
    bottom: 308.3500061035156,
    left: 348
}
```

So the following will reliably get the coordinates of a tap/click relative to the canvas element, come scroll or high water:

```
var x = event.pageX,
    y = event.pageY; // (or your preferred method, e.g. jQuery)
    bounds = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

x = x - bounds.left;
y = y - bounds.top;
```

The above is from Firefox; I found Chrome doesn't include the `x` and `y` properties, so probably best to stick to `left` and `top`. I haven't tested it on IE or Safari.

I hope this proves useful to someone else - it's been driving me nuts over the past few months. Many thanks to the questions and answers linked to here.

Finally, this answer is a neat solution whether you're using Polymer/WebComponents or not - it just so happens that that was my in-road into the problem and really threw the issue into relief.